# SQL find highest date in all entries with a date older than x

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I try to obtain a list of all customers my company has not had any assignments for in the last year.

```
SELECT MAX(assignment_date), full_name
FROM assignments 
    CROSS JOIN customers 
    WHERE assignments.customer_id = customers.id 
    AND assignment_date < '2017-01-01' -- Dynamic value from backend
GROUP BY full_name
ORDER BY assignment_date DESC
```

This does not seem to work as intended however, since it only returns some customers we *did* have assignments for in that timeframe. How would I go about implementing such a feature?

Comment: Shouldn't it be > '2017-01-01' ?

Comment: @verhie Nope, this will return all customers that did have assigments after '2017-01-01'

Comment: You want to list all customers that had no assignment since 2017-01-01? And along you want to show their last assignment date (e.g. 2016-06-30)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
  SELECT MAX(assignment_date), full_name
    FROM customers
    where id not in (SELECT id FROM customers inner join assigments on customers.id = assignments.customer_id WHERE assignment_date > '2017-01-01' )
```

This will return all customers in your database and remove all of them who did have assigments in last year. You should get all customers without assigments before '2017-01-01' as a result

Comment: Good idea, but the `assignment_date` is probably a column in `assignments` so your query needs some adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

left join customers to assignments where assignments.customer_id IS NULL
and assignment_date greater than '2017-01-01' i.e.

```
SELECT MAX(assignment_date), full_name
  FROM assignments 
 WHERE assignments.customer_id IN
   (SELECT customers.id 
      FROM customers 
      LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignments.customer_id = customers.id 
     WHERE assignments.customer_id IS NULL
       AND assignment_date > '2017-01-01')
GROUP BY full_name
ORDER BY assignment_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `left join`, `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT MAX(assignment_date), full_name
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     assignments a
     ON a.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.full_name
HAVING MAX(a.assignment_date) < '2017-01-01' OR
       MAX(a.assignment_date) IS NULL
ORDER BY MAX(assignment_date) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to show all customers with their last assignment date, but you want to restrict that list to customers that had no assignment since 2017-01-01. This means the dates you will be showing will be null for those customers who had never had an assignment and a date before 2017-01-01 for the others.

So outer join the last dates to the customers and only keep the rows where that date is before 2017-01-01 or null:

```
select c.full_name, a.max_date
from customers c
left join
(
  select customer_id, max(assignment_date) as max_date
  from assignments
  group by customer_id
) a on a.customer_id = c.customer_id
where a.max_date < date '2017-01-01'
   or a.max_date is null
order by a.max_date desc;
```